# Calling multiple files from the same folder in a single file using module exports in Node

Tags: javascript, jestjs, playwright

I'm trying to call multiple files from a single index.js file

[Here is the current file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqxVW.png)

The index.js file:

```js
const ApplicantRegister = require("./ApplicantRegister");
const ApplicantResidency = require("./ApplicantResidency");
const ApplicantPersonalDetails = require("./ApplicantPersonalDetails");
const ApplicantContactDetails = require("./ApplicantContactDetails");
const ApplicantEducation = require("./ApplicantEducation");

const models = {
  ApplicantRegister,
  ApplicantResidency,
  ApplicantPersonalDetails,
  ApplicantContactDetails,
  ApplicantEducation,
};

module.exports = models;
```

Inside new.test.js

```js
const {
  ApplicantRegister,
  ApplicantResidency,
  ApplicantPersonalDetails,
  ApplicantContactDetails,
  ApplicantEducation,
} = require("../models");
```

The files in the models folder contain a single class (example):

```js
class ApplicantRegister {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async navigate() {
    await this.page.goto(
      "https://www.google.com"
    );
  }
}
```

Which I call in new.test.js:

```js
test("Navigate to page", async () => {
    const register = new ApplicantRegister(page);
    await register.navigate();
  });
```

I get the error:
TypeError: ApplicantRegister is not a constructor

When I call the files individual (const ApplicantRegister = require("../models/ApplicantRegister") and add module.exports to the bottom of the individual files, it works.

Why does it give me the error when I try and require the files from a central file?

Comment: How are you importing them in `new.test.js`?

Comment: Are you exporting the classes in the model files?

Comment: @Phix See section "Inside new.test.js"

Comment: @slebetman Do I need to export them there also?

Comment: @Russell `module.exports = class ApplicatanRegister` — you can't require something that isn't on module.exports.

Comment: Yes. You need to export them. The module system was added by Ryan Dahl to node.js without modifying javascript. So there were and still is zero syntax changes in node.js - node uses plain javascript. So the module system had to use only design patterns which means the module system is just regular plain javascript code. That's why exports are not automatic - there is no special compiler in node.js. You have to tell the node.js "library" what you are exporting using the module "library" via `module.exports`

Comment: @ZacAnger I added module.exports = class {  ApplicantRegister; }; to the ApplicantRegister.js and it resolved that issue. However now when I call:
 await register.navigate(); 
from new.test.js it says register.navigate is not a function. Also tried module.exports = { ApplicantRegister } - it just gives the original constructor error

Answer (score 0):

The basic requirement is adding `module.exports` in each file.
To use the code present in modules you should use module.exports.

After adding `module.exports = Applicant...` in your each file you can use your index.js code.

ApplicantRegister.js

```js
class ApplicantRegister {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async navigate() {
    await this.page.goto(
      "https://www.google.com"
    );
  }
}
module.exports = ApplicantRegister;
```

your index.js is correct.

Comment: I've done this and the issue still occurs. Thanks for responding though,